# Javascript Onchange Event In the form (Getting Latitude And Longitude from Postcode)

Tags: javascript, onchange

What I'm trying to do is to get the latitude and longitude from imported postcodes.
Which works fine as long as I stick to only one input (first or second separate).
I can't get it to work once I try with both of them.
I'm using the onchange event ..

Please take a look at the form:

```
<form name="latlon" action="test2a.php" method='post' onchange="return usePointFromPostcode(document.getElementById('postcode').value) && usePointFromPostcode1(document.getElementById('postcode1').value) ">
    <input id="postcode" type="text" size="10" /><br>
    <input id="postcode1" type="text" size="10"/><br>
    Latitude:<input name="lat" type="text" id="lat" size="10"/><br />
    Longitude:<input name="lon" type="text" id="lon" size="10"/><br><br>
    Latitude:<input name="lat1" type="text" id="lat1" size="10"/><br />
    Longitude:<input name="lon1" type="text" id="lon1" size="10"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Lat / Lon"/>
</form>
```

and in JavaScript this is what I used to get latitude and longitude:

```
function usePointFromPostcode(postcode, callbackFunction) {
    localSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(null,

    function () {

        if (localSearch.results[0]) {
            var resultLat = localSearch.results[0].lat;
            var resultLng = localSearch.results[0].lng;
            var point = new GLatLng(resultLat, resultLng);
            document.forms['latlon'].lat.value = resultLat;
            document.forms['latlon'].lon.value = resultLng;
            callbackFunction(point);
        } else {
            alert("Postcode not found!");
        }
    });

    localSearch.execute(postcode + ", UK");
}

function usePointFromPostcode1(postcode1, callbackFunction) {

    localSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(null,

    function () {

        if (localSearch.results[0]) {
            var resultLat = localSearch.results[0].lat;
            var resultLng = localSearch.results[0].lng;
            var point = new GLatLng(resultLat, resultLng);
            document.forms['latlon'].lat1.value = resultLat;
            document.forms['latlon'].lon1.value = resultLng;
            callbackFunction(point);
        } else {
            alert("Postcode not found!");
        }
    });

    localSearch.execute(postcode1 + ", UK");
}
```

I'm totally stuck here. What am I doing wrong?
Will appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe i'm not clear enough here ...

all i want is to type in 2 postodes in the form so i can get their lat / lon  and pass these values to another page, (hidden inputs to be used)

im not so much into javascript but maybe there is some other way ...
problem is in the form (getting lat / lon works fine)

any suggestions ...

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<form name="latlon" action="test2a.php" method='post' onchange="return usePointFromPostcode(document.getElementById('postcode').value) && usePointFromPostcode1(document.getElementById('postcode1').value) ">
```

in

```
<form name="latlon" action="test2a.php" method='post' onchange="usePointFromPostcode(document.getElementById('postcode').value); usePointFromPostcode1(document.getElementById('postcode1').value); ">
```

I'm not sure why you were using it as return from the onchange event. As far as I know it won't be executed like you want when using `&&`.

**EDIT:**
Ah, I see something now: you are setting a callback to the localSearch variable in the first function, and you are overwriting it in the second function. That's why `document.forms['latlon'].lat` and `document.forms['latlon'].lon` will never change value. Only `lat1` and `lon1` will. (twice, probably)

You either have to create another variable like localSearch and use that for your second function.

Or most probably better; you will have to check in your callback whether it came from the first function, or from your second function. I'm not sure if that's even possible.

Comment: thank for advice, fixed onchange, still doesn't work as i shuld .. no different then before i'm afraid .. second input (postcode1) works perfectly, first input (postode) does strange ..

Answer (score 0):

Works, but is not perfect ....

```
 <input type="text" size="5"  name="postcode1" id="postcode1" maxlength="4" style="width: 32px" onchange="usePointFromPostcode(document.getElementById('postcode1').value)"  >

 <input type="text" size="5"  name="postcode2" id="postcode2" maxlength="4" style="width: 32px" onchange="usePointFromPostcode1(document.getElementById('postcode2').value)">
```

Any suggestions ....